# Check for WebGL support in Dart

Tags: webgl, dart

I'm playing with **WebGL** and **Dart** and I can't figure out how to check if some object has certain method. For example in JavaScript I would check if WebGL is available with `window.WebGLRenderingContext` but is there a way to the same in Dart?

Comment: You are asking two things here. Toji answered "how do I correctly detect WebGL is working on a machine" which really isn't a Dart-specific question. Your second question is more subtle: "In Dart, can I do feature detection via checking if an object has a certain method?" and the answer is no. In Dart, classes are defined at compile time, and the API is fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC one of the goals of Dart was to normalize the inconsistencies of which browser defines what. As such, WebGL will *always* be "available" in that the interfaces for it will always exist in Dart wether or not the browser you are running on has them defined natively.

Wether or not WebGL is supported is probably best checked the same way you do in Javascript:

```
WebGLRenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
```

If `gl` is null then WebGL is not supported. Otherwise it is!

(BTW: just because `window.WebGLRenderingContext` exists in Javascript does NOT mean that WebGL is supported! That only tells you that the browser is capable of dispatching WebGL commands. The system that you are running on may not accept them. It's still best to try creating a context and detect when it fails.)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: By the way, there is a Dart way of initializing WebGL context:

```dart
RenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext3d();
if (gl == null) {
  print("WebGL: initialization failure");
}
```

OLD ANSWER:

```dart
WebGLRenderingContext gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if (gl == null) {
    print("WebGL is not supported");
    return;
}
```

This code prints "WebGL is not supported" on Chrome JavaScript Console, when I turn on "Disable WebGL" under chrome://flags/.

However, with WebGL disabled under Firefox (about:config -> webgl.disabled;true), it yields error on Web Console:

> NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLCanvasElement.getContext]

EDIT: This is the fixed bug for Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645792